# Vue2-Leaflet with No-SSR causes Window is not defined error

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I've been trying a bunch of stuff now. I've tried nuxt-leaflet dependency, I've tried writing my own plugin and including it. However, everything keeps ending in the "window is not defined" error.

The map should only be loaded on the client.

My vue component:

```
 <template>
        <no-ssr>
            <l-map
                    id="map"
                    :zoom="zoom"
                    :min-zoom="3"
                    :center="center"
            >

            </l-map>
        </no-ssr>
 </template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import {latLng, marker} from 'leaflet';
    import {ExploreItemType} from '~/components/explore/ExploreItem';
    import {Component} from "nuxt-property-decorator";

    @Component()
    export default class ExplorerMap extends Vue {

        url = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoia2dydWVuZWJlcmciLCJhIjoiY2puajJ3c3dmMGV1YzNxbDdwZ3Y5MXc0bCJ9.kuHo67NUkzqya1NtSjTYtw';
        attribution = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';
        zoom = 3;
        center = latLng(51.505, -0.09);
        drawCluster = true;

    }
</script>
```

So I wrote my own plugin in plugins/vue-leaflet.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2Leaflet from 'vue2-leaflet'
import Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster from 'vue2-leaflet-markercluster';

Vue.component('l-circle', Vue2Leaflet.LCircle);
Vue.component('l-geo-json', Vue2Leaflet.LGeoJson);
Vue.component('l-icon-default', Vue2Leaflet.LIconDefault);
Vue.component('l-layer-group', Vue2Leaflet.LLayerGroup);
Vue.component('l-map', Vue2Leaflet.LMap);
Vue.component('l-marker', Vue2Leaflet.LMarker);
Vue.component('l-popup', Vue2Leaflet.LPopup);
Vue.component('l-tile-layer', Vue2Leaflet.LTileLayer);
Vue.component('l-tooltip', Vue2Leaflet.LTooltip);
```

And included it in the nuxt.config.js

`{src: "~/plugins/vue-leaflet.ts", ssr: false}`

No matter what I've tried, I always end up getting the window is not defined error. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because in your component you do

```
import {latLng, marker} from 'leaflet';
```

Which probably will do some window check and fail straight away. So you need to import it conditionally with `if (process.client)` check

Comment: Can you post an example of the import and the usage of the given function latLng? I've tried something like `let leaflet;if (process.client) { leaflet = require('leaflet');}` and then use leaflet. Leaflet is undefined when using the function, though.

Comment: I tried this and get error: `An import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module.` using typescript

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint from Aldarund, I got this to work:

```
<template>

    <div>
        <no-ssr>
            <l-map
                    id="map"
                    :zoom="zoom"
                    :min-zoom="3"
                    :center="center"
            >
                <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"/>
               ....
            </l-map>
        </no-ssr>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined';
    let leaflet;
    if (isBrowser) {
        leaflet = require('leaflet');
    }
    import Vue from 'vue';

    import {Component, Prop, Watch} from "nuxt-property-decorator";

    @Component({})
    export default class ExplorerMap extends Vue {

        url = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoia2dydWVuZWJlcmciLCJhIjoiY2puajJ3c3dmMGV1YzNxbDdwZ3Y5MXc0bCJ9.kuHo67NUkzqya1NtSjTYtw';
        attribution = 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>';
        zoom = 3;
        center;

        created() {
            if (isBrowser) {
                this.center = leaflet.latLng(51.505, -0.09);
            }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `nuxtjs` ,You can use the `<client-only>` component to achieve a similar dynamic import effect and dynamically import your map component, I got this to work:

```js
<template>
  <client-only>
    <YourComponent /> // forexample l-map
  </client-only>
</template>
```